# How to avoid modify initial object and improve mapping?

Tags: typescript

I have the following code, that modifes initial object and return it:

```
this.appdocspackets = this.appdocspackets.map((docpacket) => {
            let headDocument = this.setHeadDocument(docpacket.appdocs, docpacket.headappdocid);

            this.setSoglListSignators(headDocument);
            this.setCurrentPodpisant(headDocument);

            return {
                ...docpacket,
                headappdoc: headDocument,
            };
        });
```

Inside this method you can see two methods:

```
   this.setSoglListSignators(headDocument);
   this.setCurrentPodpisant(headDocument);
```

Methods are:

```
private setSoglListSignators(headDocument: AppdocExtended): void {
    let soglListSignators = [];

    if (headDocument.sogllist) {
        soglListSignators = soglListSignators.concat(headDocument.sogllist);
    } else {
        headDocument.sogllist = [];
    }

    if (headDocument.signators) {
        soglListSignators = soglListSignators.concat(headDocument.signators);
    } else {
        headDocument.signators = [];
    }

    headDocument.soglListSignators = soglListSignators;
}


private setCurrentPodpisant(headDocument: AppdocExtended): void {
    const podpisantOrSignator = this.mapCurrentPodpisantOrSignator(headDocument.podpisant, headDocument.soglListSignators);
    if (podpisantOrSignator) {
        if (podpisantOrSignator.signid) {
            headDocument.currentPodpisant = podpisantOrSignator;
        }

        if (podpisantOrSignator.soglid) {
            headDocument.currentSignator = podpisantOrSignator;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code is heavy to understand and it is not good modify initial object. How to improve this code?

Comment: Please post a workable [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/) with your full class.  I can't make sense of what's going on based on the snippets you've posted.  There are too many references to other methods and unknown types.

Comment: That said, what you want is for the two private methods to return a new `AppdocExtended` rather than being `void` methods which modify the one that they recieve.

Comment: What is your question's aim? Do you want to have a more readable code? Or do you face some side effects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is have those two private methods return a new instance of `AppdocExtended` rather than being void methods which modify the one that they receive.  If `AppdocExtended` is just a plain interface (not a class), this is easy to do with object destructuring.

For `setSoglListSignators`, my interpretation of this function is that we set `sogllist` and `signators` to an empty array if they aren't set and we set `soglListSignators` to the combination of those two arrays.

```
  private setSoglListSignators(headDocument: AppdocExtended): AppdocExtended {

    // default to empty array if not set
    const { sogllist = [], signators = [], ...rest } = headDocument;

    return {
      ...rest,
      sogllist,
      signators,
      soglListSignators: [...sogllist, ...signators]
    }
  }
```

If we want to be very explicit about our return types, we can tell typescript that the three properties which we set now definitely exist on the returned object, whereas they were optional before.

```
private setSoglListSignators(headDocument: AppdocExtended): AppdocExtended & Required<Pick<AppdocExtended, "soglListSignators" | "sogllist" | "signators">>
```